# Making sure that IE is running IE9 standards mode

Tags: internet-explorer-9, metadata, cross-browser

I need a page to always render in IE9 browser mode and document mode IE9 standards.

Can I **force** this behaviour? It seems like if the user is selecting another mode or standard there is no way to change this by setting DOCTYPE and X-UA-Compatible meta. The header of my page is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Can someone please help me figuring this out and why the browser won't go into standard IE9 mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that I can't force browser mode. It's added for development purposes. Document mode can however be changed using the doc type and the meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this http://html5boilerplate.com/html5boilerplate-site/built/en_US/docs/html/#make-sure-the-latest-version-of-ie-is-used would help you more.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It doesn't help me force the browser settings.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` since your !doctype looks more modern/html5ish?

Comment: probably only because i just added the doctype :)